# MS Access Retrieve and Modify Arguments of Steps in a Macro

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a MS Access database with a macro. The macro will, obviously, import files, run queries and generating spreadsheet reports on a daily basis.

Now I want to modify the macro to process files within a start/end date range. But the file names used in the TransferText and TransferSpreadsheet actions are all fixed and I need to separate the files into different folders.

Can I change that using VBA?

I have been try looking up in the web but I have difficulty find any resources that explain how to manipulate the actions within a macro.

File copying would be another option but I would take that as the last resort.

Comment: When you click on the Macro and open it in design mode, you can convert the entire macro to VBA, this way you can modify what you want.

Comment: @Wouter - thanks for the comment! that will be my second last resort :) Just now discovered that my Access is 2007. Does the VBA convert  available as I couldn't find it in the Design mode?

Comment: Did you try making the Design tab visible (through settings/properties)?

Comment: @FDavidov I got it now. Thanks!

Comment: What about up-voting my comment? This is the only compensation we get in here (and with no cost to you :-)).